# Knockout: Click button created server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic, knockout.js

I have a razor view with a partial view inside.

Within ProductBooking partial I am sending the data and creating a list of prices in a controller, add them to model and then display the list together with a Book Now button next to each price. Then I want to click Book now button and display another content beneath pricing details.

The problem is I cannot make the click event working on the dynamic buttons probably because the knockout model was created before them.

```
<div id="bookingForm" data-bind="visible: showBookingForm">
    <div id="pricingDetails" data-bind="visible: showPricingDetails">
        @Html.Partial("ProductBooking")
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: showBookNow">
         another content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button-block">
    <a data-bind="click: toggleBookingForm">Show booking form</a>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/booking-model.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">            
    var viewModel= new BookingViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

The buttons in the partial:

```
@foreach (PriceModel price in Model.Prices)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@price.PriceTotal</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="priceTotal" value="@price.PriceTotal" />
            <input type="button" data-bind="click: toggleBookNow" value="BookNow"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

<!-- this doesn't work -->
<script>
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
<!-- /this doesn't work -->

}
```

My knockout:

```
var BookingViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.showBookingForm = ko.observable(false);
self.showPricingDetails = ko.observable(false);
self.showBookNow = ko.observable(false);

// Toggle book now button upon click
self.toggleBookingForm = function () {
    console.log('Toggled Book Form window');
    self.showBookingForm(!self.showBookingForm());
    console.log('Toggled Pricing Details window');
    self.showPricingDetails(!self.showPricingDetails());
}

// THIS DOESN'T FIRE
self.toggleBookNow = function () {
    console.log('Toggled Book Now window');
    self.showBookNow(!self.showBookNow());
}
};
```

I tried to reapply bindings inside ProductBooking partial (see above) after I created buttons eg.

```
<script>
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

But is shouts it cannot create multiple bindings inside one element.

I also tried to change the Book now button for:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.toggleBookNow" value="BookNow"/>
```

but it doesn't change anything.

How to make the buttons binding working after I created dynamic buttons in the partial?

Comment: Your code actually works just fine within a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4usbya8/). I would recommend replacing `click: toggleBookNow` with `text: console.log($data)` to try to understand the scope better. Or I'd recommend [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof) chrome plugin for debugging knockout.

Comment: This could help:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

I did add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('button'+@counter));
</script>
```

after the snippet with the buttons, each button (and the above script) within 'button1', 'button2', 'button3' etc. div

This make it working.